# Delphi: problems with GDI+ & gradient frame/rectangle

Tags: delphi, gdi+, transparency, frame, gradient

Delphi XE2. There is a form & a frame.

The form and the frame are `doublebuffered`. `GlassFrame` is enabled.

I paint frame's background and try to draw a right aligned rectangle but have bugs. Especially I have bugs while resizing.

The rectangle doesn't want to be drawn normally from transparency to the opaque black color.
[image]

```
uses ...GDIPAPI, GDIPOBJ...
type
  TFrame2 = class(TFrame)
    procedure PaintWindow(DC: HDC); override;

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFrame2.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
var
  R: TGPRect;
  pen: TGPPen;
  Graphics: TGPGraphics;
  linGrBrush: TGPLinearGradientBrush;
begin
  R.X := 0;
  R.Y := 0;
  R.Width := self.Width;
  R.Height := self.Height;

  Graphics := TGPGraphics.Create(DC);

  linGrBrush := TGPLinearGradientBrush.Create(R, MakeColor(255, 120, 248, 253),
    MakeColor(255, 200, 216, 250), LinearGradientModeVertical);

  Graphics.FillRectangle(linGrBrush, 0, 0, R.Width, R.Height);
  linGrBrush.Free;

    linGrBrush := TGPLinearGradientBrush.Create(MakePoint(0, 0),
MakePoint(189, 2), MakeColor(0, 0, 0, 0), MakeColor(255, 0, 0, 0));

  Graphics.FillRectangle(linGrBrush, R.Width - 189, 79, 189, 2);

  linGrBrush.Free;
  Graphics.Free;
end;
```

Please help me to draw a rectangle on the gradient frame normally from transparency to the opaque black color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the code like shown below will draw a right aligned thin line from transparency to black opaque.

```
linGrBrush := TGPLinearGradientBrush.Create( 
  MakePoint(R.Width-189,0), MakePoint(R.Width,2),
  MakeColor(0, 0, 0, 0),
  MakeColor(255, 0, 0, 0));
Pen := TGPPen.Create( linGrBrush,3);
Graphics.DrawLine(Pen,R.Width-189,79,R.Width,79);
InvalidateRect(Handle,Rect(0,0,R.Width,R.Height),False);
```

**Update**, using `InvalidateRect` for the whole area forces a total redraw of the frame.
Otherwise the redraw might be clipped in strange ways.
This will solve your color change effect.

But a `GlassFrame` defect is illustrated with the last two images below. The outside frame of the TFrame is not correctly visible on the top and upper sides.

[image]

[image: GlassFrame enabled]
[image: GlassFrame disabled]

Showing dysfunction of TFrame when `GlassFrame` is enabled (left).
The right picture shows a complete black frame (even though in this picture the right side was cropped in compression) with `GlassFrame` disabled.

**Update 2 :**

Enable `SheetOfGlass` and everything seems ok.

[image]

**Update 3 :**

The `GlassFrame` top property was set to 40, and caused the strange border effect around the frame. Setting it to 0 fixed this issue.

Comment: Thanks! But it isn't what I want. Please download the project above and resize the form, you will see that colors of the rectangle change.

Comment: See my update. Still a strange effect when switching on/off glassframe. Frame edges starts around height 35 on both sides with glassframe on. Seems to be a bug in the system somewhere.

Comment: The glassframe dysfunction is more visible if you comment away the PaintWindow procedure, and switch glassframe on/off.

Comment: Ahh, you defined top = 40 in your GlassFrame properties. Setting it to zero solved the strange frame border effect.